# why when I click on the image link in the gallery it is not working?

Tags: html, wordpress

I have [this site](http://www.centerwow.com/roei/22072012/orenram/) when I click on the image.

I need to get a new page by following link **http://www.centerwow.com/main/portfolio/2/**

[image]

you can see below code:

```
<div class="box-1" style="direction: rtl;">
        <a href="http://www.centerwow.com/main/portfolio/2/"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-322" title="אתר לדוגמא" src="http://www.centerwow.com/roei/22072012/orenram/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/page1-img3.jpg" alt="" width="219" height="124"></a>        <a href="http://www.centerwow.com/main/portfolio/0/">example portfolio</a>
        <span>just click here</span>
        <p> some text</p>
    </div>
```

when I click on the image or `HTML <a> Tag` I should go to other page but nothing happens.

the same code work in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/24A9b/855/).

what should I do to make it work/go to other page.

many thanks.

Comment: The Javascript on your site is throwing errors when loading the site, you should resolve these errors (use the developer tools of your browser, or [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) in Firefox) and then check again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at "jquery.elastislide.js" file at line 92 (pointed in the below code):

```
$.elastislide.defaults = {
speed : 450, // animation speed
easing : '', // animation easing effect
imageW : 190, // the images width
margin : 3, // image margin right
border : 0, // image border
minItems : 3, // the minimum number of items to show.
// when we resize the window, this will make sure minItems are always shown
// (unless of course minItems is higher than the total number of elements)
current : 0, // index of the current item
// when we resize the window, the carousel will make sure this item is visible
--> onClick : function() { return false; } // click item callback**
};
```

just remove the "return false;" from this line